# Client credentials AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm trying to get an access token, but neither my failure or success closures are ran.

```
self.POST(tokenURL,
                 parameters: ["grant_type": "client_credentials", "client_id": "CLIENT_ID", "client_secret": "SOME_CLIENT_SECRET"],
            progress: nil,
            success: { sessionDataTask, results in
                self.accessToken = results?.objectForKey("access_token") as! String},
            failure: {operation, error in
                print("Error getting access token: \(error)")
                return}
        )
```

If I go through the browser, it does work.

Comment: You'll have to post more code. Where is the implementation of the `POST` method? What response _do_ you get? Timeout? Error?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was just ignorant here. POST was running asynchronously, so neither block ran immediately, but it does run when the response is received.